# How to quickly (vectorized?) extract varying length slices from one numpy 1D array an insert into a 2d array

Tags: python, numpy, slice

I'm trying to extract multiple, non-overlapping, slices from a single 1D numpy array into consecutive rows of a 2D array.

Let's say the source array is,

```
s=array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12])
```

and the target array is a 2D array of zeroes such as,

```
t = array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

And I want to extract the slices `[1:4:1]` and `[6:10:1]` from `s` and inject them into `t`. I have as many slices in `s` as there are rows in `t`. All slices are shorter than the row length of `t`. Each extracted slice should replace the values of the corresponding row in `t`.

The desired outcome for `t` is:

```
array([[1, 2, 3, 0, 0],
       [6, 7, 8, 9, 0]])
```

If the extracted slices were all equal length then I could do this with a 2D index array, but they are not.

I suspect I should be able to do this by creating two arrays of slices. One of them defines the slices that select the data from the source, and the other identifies the target row positions and then uses something like,

```
b[:,target_slice_array]=a[source_slice_array]
```

but I just can't figure out any syntax that works.

Here is the simple loop approach I'm using at the moment. This is what I'm trying to speed up.

```
source=np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12])
source_slices=[np.s_[0:2:1], np.s_[7:10:1]]
target_slices=[np.s_[0:2:1], np.s_[0:3:1]]

target=np.zeros(shape=(2,10), dtype=np.int32)

#for index, (source_slice, target_slice) in enumerate(zip(source_slices, target_slices)):
    #target[index,target_slice]=source[source_slice]

# Doubles the speed by moving the for loop to use range 
for index in range(len(source_slices)):
   target[index,target_slices[index] = source[source_slices[index]]
```

This updates target to,

```
[[ 0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0] 
 [ 7  9 10  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]]
```

Comment: How are you storing the slice starting and stopping indices?

Comment: I'm calculating them based on finding indices of relevant values in the 1d array. So I basically have an array of start locations and and an array of lengths

Comment: A solution using for loops is trivial - but I need this to be fast......

Comment: How about showing that trivial loop, for a start?  You can't index with an 'array of slices'.  However often you can an `advanced indexing` array to do the same thing, especially if the slices are all the same length..

Comment: @hpaulj - The slices are not the same length.

Comment: @hpaulj - I added the simple loop approach to the original post

Comment: What about using Numba or Cython for that? I expect this to be the fastest solution. For such a simple operation, Numpy temporary arrays will be expensive and a vectorized code will be at best convoluted and slower in the end (not to mention harder to maintain), especially for small arrays.

Comment: I quickly tried numba - not on the minimal example, but on my actual implementation - and it didn't help at all. Now - this was after restructuring the for loop to use the range approach instead iterating over the array directly. Still - this surprised me..... I'll be working on this again in a day or two, maybe I'll find I goofed something up....

Answer (score 1):

The following is not great, and almost certainly slower than what you have for small input, but it is fully vectorised, and may be worth doing if:

- the source index and target mask are formed once, the source data vary, and target formation is repeated; and/or
- the dimensions are huge.

In all cases, with realistic data you'll want to benchmark.

```py
import numpy as np


def multi_slice(
    source_start: np.ndarray,
    source_stop: np.ndarray,
    target_start: np.ndarray,
    target_width: int,
) -> tuple[np.ndarray, np.ndarray]:
    lengths = source_stop - source_start
    target_stop = target_start + lengths

    to_repeat = source_start.copy()
    to_repeat[1:] -= lengths[:-1].cumsum()
    idx = to_repeat.repeat(lengths)
    idx += np.arange(idx.size)

    x = np.arange(target_width)
    target_mask = (
        (x >= target_start[:, np.newaxis])
        & (x < target_stop[:, np.newaxis])
    )

    return idx, target_mask


def demo() -> None:
    # Call once
    smask, tmask = multi_slice(
        source_start=np.array((0, 7, 3)),
        source_stop=np.array((2, 10, 10)),
        target_start=np.array((0, 5, 2)),
        target_width=10,
    )

    # Run any number of times
    source = np.arange(13)
    target = np.zeros(shape=tmask.shape, dtype=source.dtype)
    target[tmask] = source[smask]
    print(target)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    demo()
```

```
[[0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 7 8 9 0 0]
 [0 0 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0]]
```